# How to add a dynamic number of fragments in android from an activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I hava a `fragment` named `DetailFragment` which `extends Fragment` class with neccessary `Override` methods:

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment{
     //Some neccessary methods are over here
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);
    return view;
    }
}
```

I hava a main activity: `FragmentActivity extends  FragmentActivity` which set content:  `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. If I want to add `DetailFragment` from `FragmentActivity`, I have to declare a `LinearLayout` (or whatever layout) with `android:id="@+id/container_fragment"` inside the `main.xml` layout file. With this way, I can add a `DetailFragment`:

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
DetailFragment df = new DetailFragment();
ft.add(R.id.container_fragment, df);
ft.commit();
```

However, I can only add 1 `DetailFragment` into that `container_fragment`. If I want to add 2 or more `DetailFragment` from the activity, do I have to add 2 or more other `container_fragment` in the `main.xml` layout? And if not, what I should do and can you give an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The layout can contain several fragments, you just have to specify different tags when calling the `add` function of the `FragmentTransaction` class.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.container_fragment, new DetailFragment(), "df_1");
ft.add(R.id.container_fragment, new DetailFragment(), "df_2");
ft.commit();
```

Comment: @Haelty Thanks for Your Help. How can i Uniquely identify the Edit text in these Fragments

Comment: When I do this, I just get 2 fragments on top of each other, taking up the full space.